# Relative path with import.meta.url

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, es6-modules

When working with ESM, quite a number of recommendation to load json file using `import.meta.url` as below

```js
import fs from 'fs';
const result = fs.readFileSync(
  new URL("abc.json", import.meta.url)
);
```

Now the above works, but with the assumption that `abc.json` is in same directory with the location of the script. I'm wondering what about relative path of the script such as `abc.json` is at one level up of directory. I tried below but it's not working

```js
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const result = fs.readFileSync(
  new URL("abc.json", path.resolve(import.meta.url, "../"))
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of applying `path.resolve` to `import.meta.url`, you should specify the relative path as the first parameter such as below

```js
const result = fs.readFileSync(
  new URL("../abc.json", import.meta.url)
);
```